# SQL how to avoid grouping by columns where not wanted

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table consisting of the following columns:

1. HouseID - INT
2. HouseType - INT
3. Location - Int
4. DateBuilt - Datetime

Basically I dont want to group on anything but HouseType but im being forced to as I dont need to aggregate certain columns.

```
SELECT [HouseType], COUNT(*), YEAR([DateBuilt]) AS YearBuilt, MONTH([DateBuilt]) AS MonthBuilt
FROM HouseTable
GROUP BY HouseType, DateBuilt
```

Can anyone help me workaround this?

---

### Sample Data

1. HouseID - 1, 2, 3
2. HouseType - 1, 1, 2
3. Location - 1, 2, 1
4. DateBuilt - '2016-12-23', '2017-02-02', '2017-01-19',

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Sure, ill see what i can do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `group by` the functions you are using instead:

```
select 
     HouseType
  ,  count(*)
  ,  year(DateBuilt) as YearBuilt
  ,  month(DateBuilt) as MonthBuilt
from HouseTable
group by 
    HouseType
  , year(DateBuilt)
  , month(DateBuilt)
```

If you wanted to keep some version of a date format, you could use `dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, DateBuilt), 0)` as an alternative, or add it to the above query:

```
select 
     HouseType
  ,  count(*)
  ,  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, DateBuilt), 0) as YearMonthBuilt
from HouseTable
group by 
    HouseType
  , dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, DateBuilt), 0)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, i had no idea you could group using YEAR, MONTH. Thanks SqlZim, this is my accepted answer.